# Migrate firebase account

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, ionic2

I'm a trainee developer in a company and I developed and App and used my firebase account, now, when we are going to release it I'm having problems to migrate the app from my firebase personal account to the company firebase account.

The iOS app migration is made but the android still linked to my old account even when I updated everywhere.

What could be the problem?

**What I have done so far:**
add google-services.json to the root of ionic 2 project

ionic platform rm --save android

ionic platform add --save android

ionic resources

cordova build --release android

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps to migrate are exactly the same of creating a new project with Firebase, you must be just forgetting something. So let's go step by step from the creation:

- You create a new Firebase Project from your company's Firebase account.
- If the config object is not given as the project is created, go to `Settings > Project Config > Add App > Add Firebase to the web`.
- Override all your `firebase.initializeApp` with the new firebase config (if you have more than one).
- In your `config.xml` give a package name to your `<widget id="packageName" ...>`, comonly it's **com.companyName.ProjectName**.
- Go to the firebase console, and on Settings add the Android and iOS projects, dont forget to use the same name as you used on the widget of the config.xml.
- Download the .json and .plist files and move then to your project root folder.
- Build the project and everything should be ok.

Be sure you don't point to the project name when making calls to Firebase, the database names probably are different so it can give errors.

Be sure you're not using the old .json file from your project instead of the newer one.

In last case, if you're willing to risk, delete your personal firebase project and see what happens. This is last case because if you can't migrate to a new one then it can give you problems because now you'll not have a database at all.

I think it's pretty much this, if following the steps still points to the old Firebase project so this must be something you're forgetting to replace.

Hope this works :)

Comment: I have done all of that... I guess I'm going to try delete the firebase project on my personal account and see what happens